# Reconstruct or Rebuild existing JSON according to parent and item id

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm generate JSON array from table value and in table I'm storing Id, Parent_id and Data and some other value. Parent_id will be `NULL` if it doesn't have any parent, if yes then it will refer parent id.

```
[{"state":"open","data":"Signature","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":2,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"or replace","attr":
{"id":1,"item_id":3,"parent_id":2}}]},{"state":"open","data":"Parameter","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":4,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"in parameter","attr":
{"id":3,"item_id":5,"parent_id":4}},{"data":"in out parameter","attr":
{"id":4,"item_id":6,"parent_id":4}}]},{"state":"open","data":"Mandatory Block","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":7,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"validate Exit condition for loop","attr":{"id":8,"item_id":8,"parent_id":7}},{"data":"validate exception","attr":
{"id":7,"item_id":9,"parent_id":7}}]},{"state":"open","data":"parent","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":10,"parent_id":7},"children":[{"data":"parent_CHILD","attr":
{"id":2,"item_id":11,"parent_id":10}},{"data":"parent_CHILD1","attr":
{"id":5,"item_id":12,"parent_id":10}}]}]
```

From above JSON, you can see `parent_id=0` means it has no parent. Now, I want to reconstruct it according to parent_id and Item_id, which means If `parent_id=0` then sort it according to item_id

Help me to figure it out.

**UPDATE**

I tried following, but unable to get desire result.

```
<script src='js/linq.js'></script>
<script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script>


var dataArray = $.parseJSON([{"state":"open","data":"Signature","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":2,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"or replace","attr":
{"id":1,"item_id":3,"parent_id":2}}]},{"state":"open","data":"Parameter","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":4,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"in parameter","attr":
{"id":3,"item_id":5,"parent_id":4}},{"data":"in out parameter","attr":
{"id":4,"item_id":6,"parent_id":4}}]},{"state":"open","data":"Mandatory Block","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":7,"parent_id":0},"children":[{"data":"validate Exit condition for loop","attr":{"id":8,"item_id":8,"parent_id":7}},{"data":"validate exception","attr":
{"id":7,"item_id":9,"parent_id":7}}]},{"state":"open","data":"parent","attr":
{"id":0,"item_id":10,"parent_id":7},"children":[{"data":"parent_CHILD","attr":
{"id":2,"item_id":11,"parent_id":10}},{"data":"parent_CHILD1","attr":
{"id":5,"item_id":12,"parent_id":10}}]}]);
var sorted = Enumerable.From(dataArray)
    .OrderBy(function(x) {
        return x.parent_id;
    })
    .ThenBy(function(x) {
        return x.item_id;
    })
    .ToArray();
console.log(sorted);
console.log(dataArray);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [linq.js](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/).

```
var dataArray = $.parseJSON(dataInYourQuestion);
var sorted = Enumerable.From(dataArray)
    .OrderBy(function(x) {
        return x.parent_id;
    })
    .ThenBy(function(x) {
        return x.item_id;
    })
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Update again, and be specific about what your "desired result" is. What is not sorted correctly, and why?